# Parse complex HTML page in ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, html-parsing, html-parser

I want to parse  complex HTML page, It contains table.What would be the best way to do this?Right now I am using TFHpple. But I am facing difficulties while parsing complex table data with different fonts.Is there any library in Objective C which give the same result like JSOUP in java.
Please help me out.

Comment: What's your end game? If you just want to display the HTML then you can use `NSAttributedString` or `UIWebView`.

Comment: No I am not displaying html in webview. I want to parse data from html page and have to show relevant data(not all) in my table view. Please suggest me any suitable library for that.

Comment: You can try NSXMLParser but it's not too reliable with HTML.